# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

i just want that if the user logs in it should echo welcome and if his name and password is wrong to ask him to reenter please help.

```html
require_once 'connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['logSubmit'])){
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $password = $_POST['psw'];
    $query ="SELECT * FROM library_db WHERE username = '$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $queryRun=$conn->query($query);
    
    $row3 = fetch_row($queryRun);
    $row3[0];
    if($row3['username'] == $username && $row3['userPassword'] == $password){
        echo '   welcome you made it to the future';
    }else{
        echo '    please enter correct details';
        }
    }
else{
    echo 'please enter correct username and password';
```

Comment: $queryRun is probably a boolean, you need to check it first. It means your query failed. You also have SQL injection present here too.

Comment: Well `fetch_row` is undefined function. It would be `$queryRun->fetch_row()`. Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Welcome on SO, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/* Here I am sharing working code */
    require_once 'connect.php';  /* database connections */
    if (isset($_POST['logSubmit'])){
    $username = (isset($_POST['uname'])) ? $_POST['uname'] : "";  /* take username from post */
    $password = (isset($_POST['psw'])) ? $_POST['psw'] : "";  /* take password from post */
    if(trim($username) != "" AND trim($password) != ""){ /* validate username and password not empty/blank */
        $query ="SELECT * FROM library_db WHERE username = '$username' and password='$password' LIMIT 1";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  /* take first row from result */
        if(count($row) > 0){ /* check if row has some data */
            echo 'welcome you made it to the future';   /* success */
        }else{
            echo 'please enter correct details';  /* no data found in result */
        }
        }else{
            echo 'please enter correct details'; /* username and/or password field empty/blank */
        }
    }else{
        echo 'please enter correct username and password'; /* logSubmit field not set */
    }`

Answer (score 1):

before using the value from the result always check if the value is present or not

```
  if((isset($row3['username']) && $row3['username'] == $username) && 
    ((isset($row3['username']) && $row3['userPassword'] == $password))
```